# Running multiple OSGi http bundles on different ports with Equinox

Tags: jetty, osgi, equinox

I want to run multiple OSGi http bundles bound to different ports. I am using Server-Side Equinox for this which uses jetty as the underlying engine for providing Servlet API support.

If I want to run just a single bundle, I can just use the property - `org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.http.port=8080`. But how can we run multiple such bundles on different ports? Is it even possible to do this using equinox jetty server?

Thanks in advance.